# Regular expression to match 2 or 21 or 210 and anything that follows

Tags: regex

I'm trying to do several hundred 301 redirects for a new site.

Each of approximately 400 store locations have to be redirected from their old URL to the new URL. The old URL looks like this:

```
https://example.com/stores/-/details/store/245
```

But sometimes (like when indexed in Google or Bing) the URLs also have long query strings after them such as:

```
https://example.com/stores/-/details/store/245?utm_source=Yext&StoreListings&utm_store_campaign=245
```

I originally used a simple greedy expression like

```
/stores/-/details/store/245.*
```

but this would redirect store 2, 24 and 245 to /stores/-/details/store/2.

I then changed it to a lazy quantifier

```
/stores/-/details/store/245*?
```

This matches the entire number correctly, but now the problem is that it will match /2 or /24 or /245, but nothing else. That is, it will match just the number, but if anything follows the number such as a query string, it won't match.

How do I get a regex that will match the entire number (be it 2, 24, or 245) with or without anything that follows it?

Comment: What about `(?:245|24|2)`?

Comment: What's the new url?

Comment: for example: http://example.com/stores/tx/plano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\b` to match a word boundary in the regular expression, then `.*` to match the rest. This will keep `2` from matching `245` because there's no word boundary between `2` and `4`.

```
/stores/-/details/store/2\b.*
```

Comment: Not working. Tried /stores/-/details/store/245(\d+).* The replacement doesn't have a store number. For example, https://example.com/stores/-/details/store/245 will redirect to https://example.com/stores/tx/plano/

Comment: Did you use `$1` in the rewrite to copy the store number?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. There is no store number in the new URL.

Comment: I thought you wanted to redirect to a different URL but keep the store number. You want to remove the store number but keep all the parameters after it?

Comment: I think I understand now, you don't need to copy anything, you just want to match.

Comment: BAM! Nailed it! That's it Barmar. Thanks! Word boundary is a new one for me. Gonna have to read up on that. Thank you!!